# Photoshop - How to Create Overlapping Stroke on Font?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typesetting

I want create a type in which the letters overlap each other (let's say -200 VA setting), and then make a stroke that will be overlapping. Letters themselves shouldn't be filled with any color, but rather stroked.

When I make the text condensed, since letters are overlapping, When I try to stroke it, it only strokes the outline of the whole word, rather than outline of each individual letter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well it would be better on Illustrator. Black stroke, no fill, compressed kerning:

[image: Rockyraw Illustrator]

I've never tried this in Photoshop but it does seem to behave strangely. This has stroke but no Fill Opacity and the letters don't seem to allow it to work as expected:

[image: Rockyraw Photoshop Weird]

If you need to do it in Photoshop then it looks like the only option is going to be to isolate each letter:

[image: Rockyraw Photoshop Solved]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed repy. this is what I'm looking for, though I don't have illustrator and there are too many letters to isolate so I wonder if there's still a way to do so. or at least a way to automatically isolate the letters into new layers without re-using the type tool for each letter?

Comment: @rockyraw There might be a script that can do it otherwise all I could suggest is downloading Inkscape, paying a one month subscription fee to use Illustrator for this, or purchase Affinity Designer. Someone else might have another idea though that I didn't think of.